# Index of the element in the series where the cumulative some is equal to or greater than 10

Tags: pandas, indexing, cumsum

I have this Panda series of integers, for example, `s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 10])`. I need to find the index of the element starting from which the cumulative sum is equal to or greater some number, for example, `10`. So, for this series since `print(s.cumsum())` gives us

```
0     1
1     3
2     6
3     7
4    12
5    22
```

I need to get `4`, because here the cumulative sum is greater than `10`.

What's the best Python way to find that index?

Comment: another way `out=s.cumsum()` finally `idx=out[out.gt(10)].index[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the condition `idxmax` after `cumsum`

```
(s.cumsum()>10).idxmax()
```